# Do switchbacks occur in the radial direction of the solar wind magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, sun, solar-wind

My question is:

When we are talking about switchbacks, do we mean switchbacks in the radial component of the magnetic field or in the total magnetic field?

Comment: I have never heard of magnetic switchbacks. Can you please provide a reference?

Comment: I mean switchbacks is the solar wind magnetic field. For reference: https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2020/new-insight-into-parker-solar-probes-early-observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of it like an S-shaped curve in a magnetic field line where the S is oriented orthogonal to the radial solar direction.  That is, looking down on the ecliptic plane and imagine the azimuthal direction is such that the radial ray we examine is along the horizontal.  In that case a magnetic field line could be traced as starting radial, then going through an upright/vertical S, and then returning to radial.  So yes, the radial component of the magnetic field reverses within switchbacks.